# How to select multiple rows

Tags: r

Let's say I have a vector that is 400 items (the contents are irrelevant, I think).

I want to select rows 1-100 and 201-300.

I would think that it would just be

```
data[1:100,201:300]
```

However, when I try this, it's only returning the first 100 rows.

For a bit more context, I'm working with a corpus that is 400 items in length, and I'm trying to pull out those rows to be my `train` model. However, when I do that, it tells me that I only have 100 documents, when I should be expecting 200.

Comment: `data[c(1:100, 201:300)]`

Comment: @alistaire `data[c(1:100, 201:300), ]`

Comment: That gives me `Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`.

Comment: @avid_useR thanks! If you want to make that an answer I'll accept it, or I can just delete the question.

Comment: Probably delete since this is certainly a duplicate. Just one tiny point: if your object has both rows and columns, then it's a data.frame or matrix, not a `vector`. Vectors are 1-dimensional and to select items from one you'd use alistaire's answer (without the comma)

Comment: (Interesting - something killed my comment) Anyway, the question being a dupe is no reason to delete it, as I said in my previous comment.

Comment: @divibisan The word "vector" is slippery in R: arrays (and therefore matrices) are vectors with a `dim` attribute, and lists (and therefore data frames) are generic vectors, so most objects in R are vectors. We usually only use the word for things without another term, but R's definition is expansive. (The issue is further complicated by the behavior of `is.vector`, which is inconsistent with the rest of the docs. `rlang::is_vector` is a consistent alternative.)

Comment: @alistaire Interesting, that's good to know. It's always nice when you learn something new while doing moderation tasks. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When subsetting a dataframe (a two-dimensional array), the first argument (before the comma) subsets the rows, while the second subsets the columns. So if we want to subset rows `1:100` and `201:300`, we feed both of them into the first argument, like the following:

```
data[c(1:100, 201:300), ]
```

**Reproducible example:**

```
mtcars[c(1:2, 4:5), ]
```

**Output:**

```
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
```

If your data is instead a one-dimensional vector (it is not clear which one from your question), then we skip the comma. But the element indices still has to be supplied as a single vector:

```
vec <- mtcars$mpg
vec[c(1:2, 4:5)]
```